# Не происходит метод добавления строки вверх при Parse

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, parse.com

Не знаю, что делаю, так уже все инструкции и весь сайт Стековерлоф перелазил. Но ошибка не исправляется. Не идет добавления новой строки вверх. Вставлял beginUpades() и endUpdates() в коде, где идет загрузка данных, вместо reloadData(). Ребята помогите, в чем может заключаться проблема. Вот мой код это метод переключения сегмента с обновление данных:

```
@IBAction func btnSegment(_ sender: Any) {
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

вставка новой строки вверх(действие не происходит):

```
func insertRow() {
    self.soccerString.insert(Soccer(), at: 0)
    tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:0, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
}
```

загрузка данных с сервера Parse.com:

```
func loadObjects1() {
    let query = Soccer.query() as! PFQuery<Soccer>

     query.findObjectsInBackground  { (objects, error) in
         if error == nil {
             self.soccerString = objects!
             self.tableView.reloadData()
          } else {
             print(error!)
          }
     }
}
```

refresh - обновления :

```
func obnova() {
    loadObjects1()
    loadObjects2()
    loadObjects3()

    insertRow()
    tableView.reloadData()
    refresh.endRefreshing()
}
```

Ребята очень буду благодарен за помощь и любую подсказку толковую!!!

Answer (score 1):

У вас довольно странный код. Вместо добавления данных в datasource для вашей tableView вы пытаетесь вставить данные прямо в таблицу, а потом делаете обновление (reloadData), таким образом затирая ваши изменения.